# Flask doesn't load current version of code

Tags: python, flask

I had this function in my flask server code:

```
@app.route('/get_video', methods=['GET'])
def get_video():
    return send_file(app.video_detection_status.path_generated_file)
```

This endpoint was access from one of the views with line:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('get_video') }}">Download video</a>
```

Now I changed the function to

```
@app.route('/get_video', methods=['GET'])
def get_video():
    return "aaaa"
```

But despite countless restarts of flask server, when I click on *Download video* in the view it still runs the old version of code (it sends me the file instead of showing `"aaaa"`).

When I delete `get_video` function completely flask notices the lack of it and throws `werkzeug.routing.BuildError` while rendering the view. And when I bring the function back (version with `return "aaaa"`) it still runs the old version (with `send_file`).

If I rename `get_video` to something else it runs the new version of code. But whenever I revert the old name the old version of code is executed.

I tried removing `*.pyc` files but it didn't help. Does flask have some kind of cache that needs to be reset? I've really run out of ideas on what might be going on here.

Comment: Are you sure that "the old code is executed"? Think about other possible sources of your problem. An obvious one is the browser cache. Now the browser _does_ obviously talk to the server. But you might have some problems in your setup that leads the browser to believe the cache is still valid based on the headers sent back by the server. So did you try to clear the browser cache first or with a different browser or a command line tool?

Comment: Thansk @ypnos, it might be a good lead. I just noticed `"GET /get_video HTTP/1.1" 200` doesn't appear in my server logs like it is for other endpoints.

Comment: Might there be another flask running in background?

Comment: Are you setting the environment variable `FLASK_DEBUG=1` before starting the app?

Comment: @DaveW.Smith No, but I do: `export FLASK_ENV=development` I guess it might be equivalent.